# How to upload image as a parameter, with other parameters using multipart form data in ios, swift3, Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm using `Alamofire 4 with swift 3` to update user profile. and also I'm using `Router` class. What I need is to `uplaod` and image with other parameters. I can `update` users detail, without uploading the image part.

this is what it looks like in `postman`

[image]

so is it possible create an urlconvertible request for this . how can I upload the image with other parametes. (this works fine in postman). how can I do this with new `Alamofire`. I tried it like below.

```
let parameters = [
            "profile_image": "swift_file.jpeg"
        ]


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1)!, withName: "file", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/png")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to:urltoUpdate)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                print("the status code is :")

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("something")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("the resopnse code is : \(response.response?.statusCode)")
                    print("the response is : \(response)")
                }
              break
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("the error is  : \(encodingError.localizedDescription)")
                break
            }
        }
```

but this didn't work properly. hope your help with this part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need this:

```
"profile_image": "swift_file.jpeg"
```

And Parameters should be:

```
let parameters = [
    "firstname": "Bill",
    "surname": "fox",
    //...rest of the parameters
]
```

And this `withName: "file"`:

```
multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1)!, withName: "file", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/png")
```

Should be `withName: "profile_image"`:

```
multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1)!, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/png")
```

Code with Headers:

```
let parameters = [
    "firstname": "Bill",
    "surname": "fox",
    //...rest of the parameters
]

let headers = [
    "somekey": "somevalue",
    //...rest of the parameters
]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1)!, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/png")

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
    }

}, usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
   to: "", //URL Here
   method: .post,
   headers: headers, //pass header dictionary here
   encodingCompletion: { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        print("the status code is :")

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("something")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print("the resopnse code is : \(response.response?.statusCode)")
            print("the response is : \(response)")
        }
        break
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print("the error is  : \(encodingError.localizedDescription)")
        break
    }
})
```

Comment: And I am also doubtful about the `mimeType: "image/png"`, because you are sending JPEG image.

Comment: so how can I upload other parameters with this `firstname, latname, such as `

Comment: Updated the code, `for (key, value) in parameters {`  loop is already binding parameters with request body.

Comment: so I have to use `for each part`, and one last thing, is it possible to send headers with this.

Comment: Updated the code, `for (key, value) in parameters {`  loop is already binding parameters with request body.

Comment: I think this will work for me. if you don't mind, please tell me how can I use `headers` with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put This method in `NSObjecte` File .

import Alamofire`

```
class func postImageToUrl(_ serverlink:String,methodname:String,param:NSDictionary,image:UIImage!,withImageName : String,CompletionHandler:@escaping (Bool,NSDictionary) -> ()) {



        print("POST : " + serverlink + methodname + " and Param \(param) ")

        var fullLink = serverlink

        if fullLink.characters.count > 0 {

            fullLink = serverlink + "/" + methodname
        }
        else {

            fullLink = methodname
        }

        var imgData = Data()
        if image != nil {

            imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)!
        }

        let notallowchar : CharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234").inverted
        let dateStr:String = "\(Date())"
        let resultStr:String = (dateStr.components(separatedBy: notallowchar) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")
        let imagefilename = resultStr + ".jpg"

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: withImageName as String, fileName: imagefilename, mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            for (key, value) in param {

                //let data = (value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                let data = (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: key as! String)

            }
        },
        usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
        to:fullLink,
        method:.post,
        headers:[:],
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {

                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default

                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                }

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    print(response)


                    if let TempresponseDict:NSDictionary = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {

                        if (TempresponseDict.object(forKey: "response") as? String)?.caseInsensitiveCompare("success") == .orderedSame {

                            CompletionHandler(true, TempresponseDict)
                        }
                        else {

                            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

                            if let error = response.result.error as? AFError {

                                statusCode = error._code // statusCode private

                                switch error {

                                case .invalidURL(let url):
                                    print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                case .parameterEncodingFailed(let reason):
                                    print("Parameter encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                case .multipartEncodingFailed(let reason):
                                    print("Multipart encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                case .responseValidationFailed(let reason):
                                    print("Response validation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")

                                    switch reason {

                                    case .dataFileNil, .dataFileReadFailed:
                                        print("Downloaded file could not be read")
                                    case .missingContentType(let acceptableContentTypes):
                                        print("Content Type Missing: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                                    case .unacceptableContentType(let acceptableContentTypes, let responseContentType):
                                        print("Response content type: \(responseContentType) was unacceptable: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                                    case .unacceptableStatusCode(let code):
                                        print("Response status code was unacceptable: \(code)")
                                        statusCode = code
                                    }
                                case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason):

                                    print("Response serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                    // statusCode = 3840 ???? maybe..
                                }

                                print("Underlying error: \(error.underlyingError)")
                            }
                            else if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {

                                print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                            }
                            else {

                                print("Unknown error: \(response.result.error)")
                            }

                            print("\(statusCode)") // the status code


                            CompletionHandler(false, TempresponseDict)
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        CompletionHandler(false, NSDictionary())
                    }
                }

                case .failure(let encodingError):

                    print(encodingError)

                    CompletionHandler(false, NSDictionary())
            }
        })

}
```

**2. Use**

```
yourNSObjectClassName.postImageToUrl(MAIN_LINK, methodname: "MethodName", param: "ParametterInDictionary", image: "UploadImage", withImageName: "ImageParametterString") { (Success, responceOBJ) in
        if Success == true
        {
            print("Your image is uploaded")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Fail")
        }
    }
```

And You are set error code of webservice to server site to show error and after you get Right success.